# appending to AM_CXXFLAGS does not work

Tags: autotools

In configure.ac i have defined AM_CXXFLAGS

```
AC_SUBS([AM_CXXFLAGS], "-Wall -Wextra -Werror -std=gnu++11"])
```

in Makefile.am i need to disable a warning in my program

```
bin_Programs = foo bar

# Works
foo_CXXFLAGS = $(AM_CXXFLAGS) -Wno-error=unused
foo_SOURCES = foo.cc

# Does not work, results in CXXFLAGS being just the -Wno-error=unused
bar_CPPFLAGS = $(AM_CPPFLAGS) -I$(top_srcdir)/include
bar_CXXFLAGS = $(AM_CXXFLAGS) -Wno-error=unused
bar_SOURCES = bar.cc
```

Why doesn't it work for bar? How to fix it?

Sidenote: The vim syntax highlighter marks the second AM_CXXFLAGS as red

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, it should be `bin_PROGRAMS`, not `bin_Programs`. It's `AC_SUBST`, not `AC_SUBS`.

Don't change `AM_*FLAGS` from the configure script, that's not how they are supposed to be used.

See the [FAQ](http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Flag-Variables-Ordering.html), it has an example of what you are trying to do; you should be `AC_SUBST`ing into a new variable, like `WARNINGCFLAGS`, and have the Makefile.am like:

```
AM_CXXFLAGS = $(WARNINGCFLAGS) -Wno-error=unused
```

and drop the `{foo|bar}_CXXFLAGS` altogether, as they are not needed after this change.

Comment: I think the root cause was that AM_*FLAGS where defined in the configure script. After i changed that, i haven't seen the problem again. Thanks.